# How do I fix discord bot disconnecting before a song is finished?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The music starts playing normally but it stops halfway through and just disconnects halfway through. There is no error on my command window. I can't seem to find any information regarding this matter.

Also I didn't have this problem before. It was still doing fine until today. Here is my index.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const {REST} = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { Player } = require("discord-player");

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const  client = new Client({
    intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    ],
  });

// List of all commands
const commands = [];
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, "commands"); // E:\yt\discord bot\js\intro\commands
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles)
{
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);

    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Add the player on the client
client.player = new Player(client, {
    ytdlOptions: {
        quality: "highestaudio",
        highWaterMark: 1 << 25
    
    },FFMPEG_OPTIONS: {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    // Get all ids of the servers
    const guild_ids = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);


    const rest = new REST({version: '9'}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);
    for (const guildId of guild_ids)
    {
        rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID, guildId), 
            {body: commands})
        .then(() => console.log('Successfully updated commands for guild ' + guildId))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if(!command) return;

    try
    {
        await command.execute({client, interaction});
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({content: "BOCCHI.EXE IS NOT WORKING \nhttps://tenor.com/view/bocchi-bocchi-the-rock-non-linear-gif-27023528"});
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

And these are my packages

```js
{
  "name": "intro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "After you have cloned the repo make sure to create a `.env` file with the `TOKEN` and `CLIENT_ID` specified for example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^1.4.0",
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.9.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.5.0",
    "@discordjs/voice": "^0.10.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.28",
    "discord-player": "^5.3.2",
    "discord.js": "^14.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^5.1.0",
    "soundcloud-scraper": "^5.0.3",
    "youtube-sr": "^4.3.4",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18"
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this error? Or is there a problem with Discord servers?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue: Apparently discord updated a change related to Voice Connections that broke apps sending 70-byte UDP packets to the voice server when using IP Discovery. While the documentation and deprecation were updated in December 2019, there wasn't communication around the the change starting to roll out so we've temporarily reverted the change to give developers more time to handle the breaking change.

The temporary fix can be found here:https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/9185

Comment: Can you add the temporary fix you mention to your answer?