# Discord-Player 5.4.0 is autopausing

Tags: discord, discord.js, ytdl

my bot worked perfectly fine earlier this week, yet for some reason it seems that 'autopausing' is enabled or is doing so without me wanting it to. I can not find anything on 'autopausing' in the docs so if someone could point me in the direction of disabling it I would be greatful.
Below are the logs acquired from the `debug` event.

```
Debug: Queue initialized:
--------------------------------------------------
Core Dependencies
- @discordjs/voice: 0.11.0
- prism-media: 1.3.5
Opus Libraries
- @discordjs/opus: 0.8.0
- opusscript: not found
Encryption Libraries
- sodium-native: not found
- sodium: not found
- libsodium-wrappers: 0.7.11
- tweetnacl: not found
FFmpeg
- version: 5.0.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
- libopus: yes
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Loaded Extractors:
None
Debug: Received play request
Debug: state change:
from {"status":"idle","resource":false,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"playing","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":0,"resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
Debug: state change:
from {"status":"playing","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":56200,"resource":true,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"autopaused","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":56200,"resource":true,"silencePacketsRemaining":5,"stepTimeout":false}
Debug: state change:
from {"status":"autopaused","missedFrames":0,"playbackDuration":56300,"resource":true,"silencePacketsRemaining":0,"stepTimeout":false}
to {"status":"idle","resource":false,"stepTimeout":false}
```

Tracks play normally for about a minute and then there is a state change to 'autopaused' and from there it is another few seconds before the bot disconnects from the vc. If I have multiple tracks in the queue it makes no difference.

Below is code for how I initialise the player:

```
// Initialise player
client.player = new Player(client, {
    ytdlOptions: {
        quality: 'highestaudio',
        highWaterMark: 1 << 25
    }
});
```

Below is code for how I initialise the queue:

```
const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild, {
                metadata: {channel: interaction.channel}, // for player_event messages
                spotifyBridge: true,
                leaveOnEnd: true
            });
```

Comment: It's weird. Someone else had the same problem a couple of hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610209/how-do-i-fix-discord-bot-disconnecting-before-a-song-is-finished Hopefully, @androz2091 (the creator of `discord-player`) will see these posts and can help you :)

Comment: this just started happening to me a couple days ago as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue on discords end right now. I was having this same problem and adding this right after creating the connection has fixed it (with a small pause).

```
    connection.on("stateChange", (oldState, newState) => {
      if (
          oldState.status === VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready &&
          newState.status === VoiceConnectionStatus.Connecting
      ) {
          connection.configureNetworking();
      }
    });
```

This is only a temporary fix. Please see [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/9185) current open issue on the discordjs repo which is where I found the temp fix.